# Returning nearest neighbors from SKLearn model deployed in AWS SageMaker

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor, amazon-sagemaker

I built an unsupervised NearestNeighbors model in AWS Sagemaker, and deployed this to an endpoint. Now, I am trying to use the model endpoint to generate the k-nearest neighbors for a given input vector.

However, I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-f595a603f928> in <module>()
     12 # print(predictor.predict(sample_vector))
     13 
---> 14 distance, indice = pred.kneighbors(sample_vector, n_neighbors=11)

AttributeError: 'SKLearnPredictor' object has no attribute 'kneighbors'
```

The SKLearn NearestNeighbors learner does not have a predict method. Trying to use the 'predict' method instead of '.kneighbors' therefore also yields an error:

```
ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (500) from model with message "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
". See https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-2#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/sagemaker-scikit-learn-2019-06-29-13-11-50-512 in account 820407560908 for more information.
```

Is there a way to call this endpoint within Sagemaker, or does the Sagemaker SKLearn SDK only allow for models with a 'predict' method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At inference, 3 functions are used one after the other: `input_fn`, `predict_fn`, `output_fn`. They take default values, but you can override them to do desired custom actions. In your case, you can for example override the `predict_fn` to run the desired command. See more details here https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_sklearn.html#deploying-scikit-learn-models

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for days looking at predict_fn and other places. In my case I was invoking the endpoint in a python lambda function, if you just add `Accept='application/json; verbose=True'` as an additional argument it outputs distances. For other output options: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/kNN-inference-formats.html

```
import boto3
runtime= boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')
payload = '1,2,3' #comma separated string
response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
                                               ContentType='text/csv',
                                               Body=payload,
                                               Accept='application/json; verbose=True')
```